# Datamapper (ruby) - (Using the blog example) Getting the posts that don't have comments

Tags: ruby, datamapper

First SO question after using this place for reference on a lot of other things.. I'm nervous.

DataMapper.. Using Blog model for example (posts, comments etc - http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html) I'm trying to workout how to get the blog posts that don't have any comments..

So something like Post.all(:comments => { :comment => nil })

Lot having much luck :(

I read on here that for complex reporting queries it's best to drop down to SQL, but surely there's a way of doing this isn't there SO?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing how your table structure looks like

Comment: Given that a Blog is a web-based application, would it be out of order to ask if this is in fact a Rails question?  (If it is, adding the 'ruby-on-rails' tag might be an idea.)

Comment: Not a rails app, just some messing around in Sinatra. As for table structure, just 2 tables, Posts and Comments, Posts can have many comments. Need the Posts that don't yet have comments...

Comment: Instead of tagging 'ruby-on-rails' you probably want to tag it 'active-record' or so...

Comment: I could probably help you better if I could see an example of your models, but with DataMapper 0.10.2 try: Post.all(:comments.not => nil)

If this does not work, please update your example with your models and I'll give it another shot.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a counter cache in your Post model (called eg "comments_count"), this is going to be slow. But here it is anyway:

```
Post.find(:all, :include => :comments).select { |post| post.comments.empty? }
```

I would suggest going with the counter cache solution (but that involves some schema refactoring and updating the counters during migration one time):

```
Post.all(:conditions => { :comments_count => 0 })
```

The latter being much more efficient, especially in Rails 3 (cause of lazy querying).

Comment: Also if you're looking for only messages with comments, you can use: `Post.find(:all, :include => :comments).select{ |post| post.comments.any?}`